# Python code in GDB init file .gdbinit

Tags: python, qt, gdb

I'm trying to create a `~/.gdbinit` that contains some Qt pretty printers for various Qt objects, especially QStrings.   I want to do this without Qt Creator, using regular GDB.  This is what I've placed into the file (This script is my modified form of the scipts at [Niko's Blog](http://nikosams.blogspot.com/2009/10/gdb-qt-pretty-printers.html)):

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-
# Pretty-printers for Qt4.

# Copyright (C) 2009 Niko Sams <niko.sams@gmail.com>

# This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

import gdb
import itertools
import re
import sys

class QStringPrinter:

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def to_string(self):
        #ret = ""
        #i = 0
        size = self.val['d']['size']
        #while i < size:
        #    char = self.val['d']['data'][i]
        #    if (char > 127):
        #        ret += "\\u%x" % int(char)
        #    else:
        #        ret += chr(char)
        #    i = i + 1
        #return ret
        dataAsCharPointer = self.val['d']['data'].cast(gdb.lookup_type("char").pointer())
        return dataAsCharPointer.string(encoding = 'UTF-16', length = size * 2)

    def display_hint (self):
        return 'string'


class QByteArrayPrinter:

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    class _iterator:
        def __init__(self, data, size):
            self.data = data
            self.size = size
            self.count = 0

        def __iter__(self):
            return self

        def next(self):
            if self.count >= self.size:
                raise StopIteration
            count = self.count
            self.count = self.count + 1
            return ('[%d]' % count, self.data[count])

    def children(self):
        return self._iterator(self.val['d']['data'], self.val['d']['size'])

    def to_string(self):
        #todo: handle charset correctly
        return self.val['d']['data'].string()

    def display_hint (self):
        return 'string'

class QListPrinter:
    "Print a QList"

    class _iterator:
        def __init__(self, nodetype, d):
            self.nodetype = nodetype
            self.d = d
            self.count = 0

        def __iter__(self):
            return self

        def next(self):
            if self.count >= self.d['end'] - self.d['begin']:
                raise StopIteration
            count = self.count
            array = self.d['array'][self.d['begin'] + count]

            #from QTypeInfo::isLarge
            isLarge = self.nodetype.sizeof > gdb.lookup_type('void').pointer().sizeof

            #isStatic is not needed anymore since Qt 4.6
            #isPointer = self.nodetype.code == gdb.TYPE_CODE_PTR
            #
            ##unfortunately we can't use QTypeInfo<T>::isStatic as it's all inlined, so use
            ##this list of types that use Q_DECLARE_TYPEINFO(T, Q_MOVABLE_TYPE)
            ##(obviously it won't work for custom types)
            #movableTypes = ['QRect', 'QRectF', 'QString', 'QMargins', 'QLocale', 'QChar', 'QDate', 'QTime', 'QDateTime', 'QVector',
            #    'QRegExpr', 'QPoint', 'QPointF', 'QByteArray', 'QSize', 'QSizeF', 'QBitArray', 'QLine', 'QLineF', 'QModelIndex', 'QPersitentModelIndex',
            #    'QVariant', 'QFileInfo', 'QUrl', 'QXmlStreamAttribute', 'QXmlStreamNamespaceDeclaration', 'QXmlStreamNotationDeclaration',
            #    'QXmlStreamEntityDeclaration']
            #if movableTypes.count(self.nodetype.tag):
            #    isStatic = False
            #else:
            #    isStatic = not isPointer
            isStatic = False

            if isLarge or isStatic: #see QList::Node::t()
                node = array.cast(gdb.lookup_type('QList<%s>::Node' % self.nodetype).pointer())
            else:
                node = array.cast(gdb.lookup_type('QList<%s>::Node' % self.nodetype))
            self.count = self.count + 1
            return ('[%d]' % count, node['v'].cast(self.nodetype))

    def __init__(self, val, container, itype):
        self.val = val
        self.container = container
        if itype == None:
            self.itype = self.val.type.template_argument(0)
        else:
            self.itype = gdb.lookup_type(itype)

    def children(self):
        return self._iterator(self.itype, self.val['d'])

    def to_string(self):
        if self.val['d']['end'] == self.val['d']['begin']:
            empty = "empty "
        else:
            empty = ""

        return "%s%s<%s>" % ( empty, self.container, self.itype )

class QVectorPrinter:
    "Print a QVector"

    class _iterator:
        def __init__(self, nodetype, d, p):
            self.nodetype = nodetype
            self.d = d
            self.p = p
            self.count = 0

        def __iter__(self):
            return self

        def next(self):
            if self.count >= self.p['size']:
                raise StopIteration
            count = self.count

            self.count = self.count + 1
            return ('[%d]' % count, self.p['array'][count])

    def __init__(self, val, container):
        self.val = val
        self.container = container
        self.itype = self.val.type.template_argument(0)

    def children(self):
        return self._iterator(self.itype, self.val['d'], self.val['p'])

    def to_string(self):
        if self.val['d']['size'] == 0:
            empty = "empty "
        else:
            empty = ""

        return "%s%s<%s>" % ( empty, self.container, self.itype )

class QLinkedListPrinter:
    "Print a QLinkedList"

    class _iterator:
        def __init__(self, nodetype, begin, size):
            self.nodetype = nodetype
            self.it = begin
            self.pos = 0
            self.size = size

        def __iter__(self):
            return self

        def next(self):
            if self.pos >= self.size:
                raise StopIteration

            pos = self.pos
            val = self.it['t']
            self.it = self.it['n']
            self.pos = self.pos + 1
            return ('[%d]' % pos, val)

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.itype = self.val.type.template_argument(0)

    def children(self):
        return self._iterator(self.itype, self.val['e']['n'], self.val['d']['size'])

    def to_string(self):
        if self.val['d']['size'] == 0:
            empty = "empty "
        else:
            empty = ""

        return "%sQLinkedList<%s>" % ( empty, self.itype )

class QMapPrinter:
    "Print a QMap"

    class _iterator:
        def __init__(self, val):
            self.val = val
            self.ktype = self.val.type.template_argument(0)
            self.vtype = self.val.type.template_argument(1)
            self.data_node = self.val['e']['forward'][0]
            self.count = 0

        def __iter__(self):
            return self

        def payload (self):

            #we can't use QMapPayloadNode as it's inlined
            #as a workaround take the sum of sizeof(members)
            ret = self.ktype.sizeof
            ret += self.vtype.sizeof
            ret += gdb.lookup_type('void').pointer().sizeof

            #but because of data alignment the value can be higher
            #so guess it's aliged by sizeof(void*)
            #TODO: find a real solution for this problem
            ret += ret % gdb.lookup_type('void').pointer().sizeof

            ret -= gdb.lookup_type('void').pointer().sizeof
            return ret

        def concrete (self, data_node):
            node_type = gdb.lookup_type('QMapNode<%s, %s>' % (self.ktype, self.vtype)).pointer()
            return (data_node.cast(gdb.lookup_type('char').pointer()) - self.payload()).cast(node_type)

        def next(self):
            if self.data_node == self.val['e']:
                raise StopIteration
            node = self.concrete(self.data_node).dereference()
            if self.count % 2 == 0:
                item = node['key']
            else:
                item = node['value']
                self.data_node = node['forward'][0]

            result = ('[%d]' % self.count, item)
            self.count = self.count + 1
            return result


    def __init__(self, val, container):
        self.val = val
        self.container = container

    def children(self):
        return self._iterator(self.val)

    def to_string(self):
        if self.val['d']['size'] == 0:
            empty = "empty "
        else:
            empty = ""

        return "%s%s<%s, %s>" % ( empty, self.container, self.val.type.template_argument(0), self.val.type.template_argument(1) )

    def display_hint (self):
        return 'map'

class QHashPrinter:
    "Print a QHash"

    class _iterator:
        def __init__(self, val):
            self.val = val
            self.d = self.val['d']
            self.ktype = self.val.type.template_argument(0)
            self.vtype = self.val.type.template_argument(1)
            self.end_node = self.d.cast(gdb.lookup_type('QHashData::Node').pointer())
            self.data_node = self.firstNode()
            self.count = 0

        def __iter__(self):
            return self

        def hashNode (self):
            "Casts the current QHashData::Node to a QHashNode and returns the result. See also QHash::concrete()"
            return self.data_node.cast(gdb.lookup_type('QHashNode<%s, %s>' % (self.ktype, self.vtype)).pointer())

        def firstNode (self):
            "Get the first node, See QHashData::firstNode()."
            e = self.d.cast(gdb.lookup_type('QHashData::Node').pointer())
            #print "QHashData::firstNode() e %s" % e
            bucketNum = 0
            bucket = self.d['buckets'][bucketNum]
            #print "QHashData::firstNode() *bucket %s" % bucket
            n = self.d['numBuckets']
            #print "QHashData::firstNode() n %s" % n
            while n:
                #print "QHashData::firstNode() in while, n %s" % n;
                if bucket != e:
                    #print "QHashData::firstNode() in while, return *bucket %s" % bucket
                    return bucket
                bucketNum += 1
                bucket = self.d['buckets'][bucketNum]
                #print "QHashData::firstNode() in while, new bucket %s" % bucket
                n -= 1
            #print "QHashData::firstNode() return e %s" % e
            return e


        def nextNode (self, node):
            "Get the nextNode after the current, see also QHashData::nextNode()."
            #print "******************************** nextNode"
            #print "nextNode: node %s" % node
            next = node['next'].cast(gdb.lookup_type('QHashData::Node').pointer())
            e = next

            #print "nextNode: next %s" % next
            if next['next']:
                #print "nextNode: return next"
                return next

            #print "nextNode: node->h %s" % node['h']
            #print "nextNode: numBuckets %s" % self.d['numBuckets']
            start = (node['h'] % self.d['numBuckets']) + 1
            bucketNum = start
            #print "nextNode: start %s" % start
            bucket = self.d['buckets'][start]
            #print "nextNode: bucket %s" % bucket
            n = self.d['numBuckets'] - start
            #print "nextNode: n %s" % n
            while n:
                #print "nextNode: in while; n %s" % n
                #print "nextNode: in while; e %s" % e
                #print "nextNode: in while; *bucket %s" % bucket
                if bucket != e:
                    #print "nextNode: in while; return bucket %s" % bucket
                    return bucket
                bucketNum += 1
                bucket = self.d['buckets'][bucketNum]
                n -= 1
            #print "nextNode: return e %s" % e
            return e

        def next(self):
            "GDB iteration, first call returns key, second value and then jumps to the next hash node."
            if self.data_node == self.end_node:
                raise StopIteration

            node = self.hashNode()

            if self.count % 2 == 0:
                item = node['key']
            else:
                item = node['value']
                self.data_node = self.nextNode(self.data_node)

            self.count = self.count + 1
            return ('[%d]' % self.count, item)

    def __init__(self, val, container):
        self.val = val
        self.container = container

    def children(self):
        return self._iterator(self.val)

    def to_string(self):
        if self.val['d']['size'] == 0:
            empty = "empty "
        else:
            empty = ""

        return "%s%s<%s, %s>" % ( empty, self.container, self.val.type.template_argument(0), self.val.type.template_argument(1) )

    def display_hint (self):
        return 'map'

class QDatePrinter:

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def to_string(self):
        julianDay = self.val['jd']

        if julianDay == 0:
            return "invalid QDate"

        # Copied from Qt sources
        if julianDay >= 2299161:
            # Gregorian calendar starting from October 15, 1582
            # This algorithm is from Henry F. Fliegel and Thomas C. Van Flandern
            ell = julianDay + 68569;
            n = (4 * ell) / 146097;
            ell = ell - (146097 * n + 3) / 4;
            i = (4000 * (ell + 1)) / 1461001;
            ell = ell - (1461 * i) / 4 + 31;
            j = (80 * ell) / 2447;
            d = ell - (2447 * j) / 80;
            ell = j / 11;
            m = j + 2 - (12 * ell);
            y = 100 * (n - 49) + i + ell;
        else:
            # Julian calendar until October 4, 1582
            # Algorithm from Frequently Asked Questions about Calendars by Claus Toendering
            julianDay += 32082;
            dd = (4 * julianDay + 3) / 1461;
            ee = julianDay - (1461 * dd) / 4;
            mm = ((5 * ee) + 2) / 153;
            d = ee - (153 * mm + 2) / 5 + 1;
            m = mm + 3 - 12 * (mm / 10);
            y = dd - 4800 + (mm / 10);
            if y <= 0:
                --y;
        return "%d-%02d-%02d" % (y, m, d)

class QTimePrinter:

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def to_string(self):
        ds = self.val['mds']

        if ds == -1:
            return "invalid QTime"

        MSECS_PER_HOUR = 3600000
        SECS_PER_MIN = 60
        MSECS_PER_MIN = 60000

        hour = ds / MSECS_PER_HOUR
        minute = (ds % MSECS_PER_HOUR) / MSECS_PER_MIN
        second = (ds / 1000)%SECS_PER_MIN
        msec = ds % 1000
        return "%02d:%02d:%02d.%03d" % (hour, minute, second, msec)

class QDateTimePrinter:

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def to_string(self):
        #val['d'] is a QDateTimePrivate, but for some reason casting to that doesn't work
        #so work around by manually adjusting the pointer
        date = self.val['d'].cast(gdb.lookup_type('char').pointer());
        date += gdb.lookup_type('int').sizeof #increment for QAtomicInt ref;
        date = date.cast(gdb.lookup_type('QDate').pointer()).dereference();

        time = self.val['d'].cast(gdb.lookup_type('char').pointer());
        time += gdb.lookup_type('int').sizeof + gdb.lookup_type('QDate').sizeof #increment for QAtomicInt ref; and QDate date;
        time = time.cast(gdb.lookup_type('QTime').pointer()).dereference();
        return "%s %s" % (date, time)

class QUrlPrinter:

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def to_string(self):
        try:
            return self.val['d']['encodedOriginal']
        except RuntimeError, error:
            #if no debug information is avaliable for Qt, try guessing the correct address for encodedOriginal
            #problem with this is that if QUrlPrivate members get changed, this fails
            offset = gdb.lookup_type('int').sizeof
            offset += offset % gdb.lookup_type('void').pointer().sizeof #alignment
            offset += gdb.lookup_type('QString').sizeof * 6
            offset += gdb.lookup_type('QByteArray').sizeof
            encodedOriginal = self.val['d'].cast(gdb.lookup_type('char').pointer());
            encodedOriginal += offset
            encodedOriginal = encodedOriginal.cast(gdb.lookup_type('QByteArray').pointer()).dereference();
            encodedOriginal = encodedOriginal['d']['data'].string()
            return encodedOriginal

class QSetPrinter:
    "Print a QSet"

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    class _iterator:
        def __init__(self, hashIterator):
            self.hashIterator = hashIterator
            self.count = 0

        def __iter__(self):
            return self

        def next(self):
            if self.hashIterator.data_node == self.hashIterator.end_node:
                raise StopIteration

            node = self.hashIterator.hashNode()

            item = node['key']
            self.hashIterator.data_node = self.hashIterator.nextNode(self.hashIterator.data_node)

            self.count = self.count + 1
            return ('[%d]' % (self.count-1), item)

    def children(self):
        hashPrinter = QHashPrinter(self.val['q_hash'], None)
        hashIterator = hashPrinter._iterator(self.val['q_hash'])
        return self._iterator(hashIterator)

    def to_string(self):
        if self.val['q_hash']['d']['size'] == 0:
            empty = "empty "
        else:
            empty = ""

        return "%sQSet<%s>" % ( empty , self.val.type.template_argument(0) )


class QCharPrinter:

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def to_string(self):
        return unichr(self.val['ucs'])

    def display_hint (self):
        return 'string'

def register_qt4_printers (obj):
    if obj == None:
        obj = gdb

    obj.pretty_printers.append (lookup_function)

def lookup_function (val):
    "Look-up and return a pretty-printer that can print val."

    # Get the type.
    type = val.type;

    # If it points to a reference, get the reference.
    if type.code == gdb.TYPE_CODE_REF:
        type = type.target ()

    # Get the unqualified type, stripped of typedefs.
    type = type.unqualified ().strip_typedefs ()

    # Get the type name.
    typename = type.tag
    if typename == None:
        return None

    # Iterate over local dictionary of types to determine
    # if a printer is registered for that type.  Return an
    # instantiation of the printer if found.
    for function in pretty_printers_dict:
        if function.search (typename):
            return pretty_printers_dict[function] (val)

    # Cannot find a pretty printer.  Return None.
    return None

def build_dictionary ():
    pretty_printers_dict[re.compile('^QString$')] = lambda val: QStringPrinter(val)
    pretty_printers_dict[re.compile('^QByteArray$')] = lambda val: QByteArrayPrinter(val)
    pretty_printers_dict[re.compile('^QList<.*>$')] = lambda val: QListPrinter(val, 'QList', None)
    pretty_printers_dict[re.compile('^QStringList$')] = lambda val: QListPrinter(val, 'QStringList', 'QString')
    pretty_printers_dict[re.compile('^QQueue')] = lambda val: QListPrinter(val, 'QQueue', None)
    pretty_printers_dict[re.compile('^QVector<.*>$')] = lambda val: QVectorPrinter(val, 'QVector')
    pretty_printers_dict[re.compile('^QStack<.*>$')] = lambda val: QVectorPrinter(val, 'QStack')
    pretty_printers_dict[re.compile('^QLinkedList<.*>$')] = lambda val: QLinkedListPrinter(val)
    pretty_printers_dict[re.compile('^QMap<.*>$')] = lambda val: QMapPrinter(val, 'QMap')
    pretty_printers_dict[re.compile('^QMultiMap<.*>$')] = lambda val: QMapPrinter(val, 'QMultiMap')
    pretty_printers_dict[re.compile('^QHash<.*>$')] = lambda val: QHashPrinter(val, 'QHash')
    pretty_printers_dict[re.compile('^QMultiHash<.*>$')] = lambda val: QHashPrinter(val, 'QMultiHash')
    pretty_printers_dict[re.compile('^QDate$')] = lambda val: QDatePrinter(val)
    pretty_printers_dict[re.compile('^QTime$')] = lambda val: QTimePrinter(val)
    pretty_printers_dict[re.compile('^QDateTime$')] = lambda val: QDateTimePrinter(val)
    pretty_printers_dict[re.compile('^QUrl$')] = lambda val: QUrlPrinter(val)
    pretty_printers_dict[re.compile('^QSet<.*>$')] = lambda val: QSetPrinter(val)
    pretty_printers_dict[re.compile('^QChar$')] = lambda val: QCharPrinter(val)


pretty_printers_dict = {}

build_dictionary ()

register_qt4_printers (None)

end
set print pretty 1
```

When I start up GDB, I get this error:

```
GNU gdb (GDB) Fedora (7.4.50.20120120-54.fc17)
<!-- Standard GPL message -->
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
/home/ben/.gdbinit:19: Error in sourced command file:
Undefined command: "import".  Try "help".
```

It appears to be failing at the first `import` statement.  What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

I have tried adding `#!/usr/bin/python` as the first line and it makes no difference.  Fails with the same error.  This is the location I get when I do `which python`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You haven't called python, just add `python` to the start of the file.  Remember this script is just executed in the GDB shell, it doesn't know it should be parsed by the python interpreter unless you tell it.

This is start and end of mine for example:

```
python
import sys 
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/cmannett85/PrettyPrinters')

...

end
```

Comment: I tried adding `#!/usr/bin/python` to the beginning, and it made no difference.  Is there a different way?

Comment: Thanks for the example.  That fixed it up

Answer (score 0):

considering cmannett85 answer, did you try putting your code not in a gdb init file but in the plcament that Qt Creator is providing for that purpose:

In Qt Creator option, debugger, gdb: Extra debugger command (For plain command)
- You may also use the provided field (Debugger Helper customization) where you can add you own debugger code in Python.

Qt Creator will automatically load the file or start the command you specify.

Regards

Comment: Please share an example to make it more understandable. Thanks in advance.