# How to use python into gdbinit script

Tags: python, gdb, gdbinit

I use `gdbinit` file to run few commands when gdb is init.

How can I use there python command? Instead using  `x/x $pc` I want to print with `binascii` 10 bytes after $PC register.

How can I do that?

Comment: Does this help?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16553345/4885321

Comment: @alagner . No because I didn't understand how to take the value from python to gdb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46573191/50617) with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6104224/50617) we end up with:

```
(gdb) x/10x $pc
0x55555555515d <main+8>:        0x48    0x8d    0x35    0xa0    0x0e    0x00    0x00    0x48
0x555555555165 <main+16>:       0x8d    0x3d

(gdb) source .gdbinit.py
488d35a00e0000488d3d
```

where `.gdbinit.py` contains:

```
import binascii
import gdb

i = gdb.inferiors()[0]
pc = gdb.parse_and_eval("$pc")
m = i.read_memory(pc, 10)
print binascii.hexlify(m)
```